# Double Sided Printed Circuit Board

Tags: pcb

New to this forum and literally do not know anything about electrical engineering.

I have a simple question for you as I am looking for some informed opinion in order to decide wether to invest in a stock or not..

This company: https://www.nano-di.com/investor-news/hensoldt-and-nano-dimension-achieve-breakthrough-in-electronics-3d-printing

just announced that it's capable of 3d printing a double sided circuit board. Apparently that was not possible and it is a world's first.

Could you tell me how much of a breakthrough is their technology? Is it something remarkable or not so much? Could you help me understand in a nutshell what is that about?

Thank you so much in advance for your patience.

Comment: Voting to close as this is not about electrical engineering per se., and could easily be spam.  But in general, if a company is trying to sell horse turds, it'll tell you that they're an amazing innovation in organic fertilizer (and they'll pay employees to pose as investors to ask questions on the internet) -- so keep that in mind when reading any company's web site.

Comment: So much diffidence. I genuinely just wanted an opinion on the technology as this company is traded on the stock market and I'm wondering if to invest in it.  I hear you tho.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Standard double sided PCBA manufacturing requires 2 passes through the reflow oven.
This means the components on the 1st side and the board itself go through two reflow thermal profiles. Not all components can tolerate that, most notably modules and older T.H connectors.

Nano-Di probably managed to invent a material and 3d printing process that allows more than one pass.

Comment: Amazing, thanks! So it does feel a solid advancement correct?

Comment: @IvanOlita nah, most things in engineering are incremental. I can't find a single thing in my head that makes this an overly useful thing. It certainly has a niche use, otherwise a large defense company wouldn't have spent time developing that. The whole article you link to is pure spam, though, and that severely turns me off as technically versed potential investor. Post their marketing s...tuff elsewhere, would be my verdict

Comment: @MarcusMüller Thanks for this. I'm still not clear on wether this is a breakthrough or not but I guess everyone thinks this is spam for some reason... What I sent is not an article but the press release from the company itself.. I'm just trying to gage wether it is a relevant tech advancement or no..but I feel you guys. apparently not the right place to ask. Thanks!~

Comment: Ok, if you need it spelled out: **this is not a breakthrough**. Better now? Also, Hensoldt is a defense company. They are inherently large enough to buy Nano-Di if they deemed the technology mature and critical for their process. The fact that they're doing a press release instead of doing just that means it's not critical. Move on.

Comment: Thank you Marcus! I was more interested in the technical element and you've helped me. Have a good one!